# Vue.js & Jest - The right way to wait for a promise to be fully handled (including clause finally) before performing assertion

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a component which behaviour looks like this one:

```js
@Component
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  public result: number = 0;

  public ready: boolean = false;
  
  // for test purpose only. In the real code, this promise is the result of a call to a dependency service.
  public promise!: Promise<void>;

  private myMethod(): void {
    this.promise
      .then(() => {
        this.result = 1;
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.result = 2;
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.ready = true;
        // setTimeout(() => {
        //   this.finallyExecuted = true;
        // }, 50);
      });
  }
}
```

The execution of a method, triggered from a click on the following button, depends from the resolution of a promise.

```html
<button id="myButton" type="button" @click="myMethod()">My button</button>
```

I want to unit test this behaviour, using Jest.

```js
// variable 'wrapper' contains the result of a shallow mount of the component, using vue-test-utils
// variable 'component' contains 'wrapper.vm', after the component has been shallow mounted

it('should set the result to 1 and be ready', async () => {
  // Given
  component.promise = Promise.resolve();

  // When
  wrapper.find('#myButton').trigger('click');
  await expect(component.promise).resolves.toBeUndefined();

  // Then
  expect(component.result).toBe(1);
  expect(component.ready).toBe(true);
});

it('should set the result to 2 and be ready', async () => {
  // Given
  component.promise = Promise.reject();

  // When
  wrapper.find('#myButton').trigger('click');
  await expect(component.promise).rejects.toBeUndefined();

  // Then
  expect(component.result).toBe(2);
  expect(component.ready).toBe(true);
});
```

These 2 unit tests fail because Jest does not wait for the `finally` clause to be executed before performing the last assertion: the assertion on `result` passes, but `ready` is seen as `false` in both cases.

How can I order Jest to wait for the promise to be fully handled, including the `finally` clause? If possible, without the use of an additional library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `promise` call inside `myMethod` is not awaited, so your test is checking for the results of the call before it's actually occurred.

The solution is for `myMethod` to return the result of the `promise` call:

```js
public myMethod(promise: Promise<void>) {
  return promise
    .then(() => {
      this.result = 1;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      this.result = 2;
    })
    .finally(() => {
      this.ready = true;
    });
}
```

Then your tests could await the result:

```js
await component.myMethod(promise);
```

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-contrib/vue-await-promise-in-jest)

Comment: In the real case, I can't catch the return of myMethod. I will make it private in my code sample to reflect that.

Comment: You should still be able to await the call. Why do you say you can't "catch the return of myMethod"?

Comment: I just edited my quesiton.
But awaiting for both the click and the promise resolution seems to work, even if I don't understand why.